# Empty DB without generated entities with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

Many many times I tried to create tables in my DB. But anything has happened. I tried everything which is connected with this issue, from Stack overflow and everything else.

I really need you for your help, because I can not continue with my project. Until now I started with my POJO classes to create a database with the entity in the same way, but today does not work. And I really do not understand.

Here is everything from my code up to now.

**Project structure:**

````
 shop
.idea
.mvn
src
main
java
shop
model
ServletInitializer
ShopApplication
resources
test
target
.gitignore
HELP.md
mvnw
mvnw.cmd
pom.xml
shop.iml    ```





**Application properties:**

```    ##Data Source Properties
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shop_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 12345

#JPA Properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = TRUE
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl = true
spring.jpa.show-sql= true

###Logging Levels
# Disable the default loggers
logging.level.org = WARN
logging.level.blog = WARN

#Show SQL executed with parameter bindings
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL = DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor = TRACE

```




**My POM.file**

```project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
<relativePath/>
<!--  lookup parent from repository  -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>shop</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>com.example.shop</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
<java.version>14</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
<scope>runtime</scope>
<optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
<exclusions>
<exclusion>
<groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
<artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
</exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>    ```



 

Thank you very much :)
````

Answer (score 1):

I have found the decision about the problem. It has been the wrong relation between entities.

I hope that this decision will be useful for somebody else.